# When Using "BlocBuilder" in "MultiBlocProvider" I have get error

Tags: flutter, bloc, cubit

I am new in flutter .I am tried googling but I cant fix my problem. I used "MultiBlocProvider" for manage stats . I want change dark mode state like bellow.

**ThemeCubit.dart**

```
part 'theme_state.dart';

class ThemeCubit extends HydratedCubit<ThemeState> {
   ThemeCubit() : super(ThemeState(AppThemes.lightTheme));

   void getTheme(ThemeState state) {
       emit(state);
   }

  @override
  ThemeState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return json['isDark'] as bool
        ? ThemeState(AppThemes.darkTheme)
        : ThemeState(AppThemes.lightTheme);
  }

 @override
 Map<String, bool>? toJson(ThemeState state) {
    return {'isDark': state.themeData.brightness == Brightness.dark};
 }
}
```

**ThemeState.dart**

```
part of 'theme_cubit.dart';

@immutable
class ThemeState extends Equatable {
  final ThemeData themeData;

  const ThemeState(this.themeData);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [themeData];
}
```

**main.dart**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
     const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    // This widget is the root of your application.
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return  MultiBlocProvider(
           providers: [
              BlocProvider(
                  lazy: true,
                 create: (context) => ThemeCubit(),
              ),
           ],
          child:BlocBuilder<ThemeCubit, ThemeState>(
             builder: (context,state) {
                 return MaterialApp(           
                     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,            
                     title: 'Flutter Production Boilerplate',
                     theme: state.themeData, //ThemeMode.dark,
                     home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
                 );
                },
               ),
              );
            }
         }
```

**settingScreen.dart**

```
Positioned(
                  top: 60 - widget.offset / 2,
                  left: 20,
                  child: Builder(builder: (context) {

                    return Switch(
                        value:newValue ,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          BlocProvider.of<ThemeCubit>(context).getTheme(ThemeState(
                              newValue ? AppThemes.darkTheme : AppThemes.lightTheme));
                        });
                  })
            ),
```

This code works properly when used "BlocProvider" . But when I used "MultiBlocProvider", I get bellow error.

> The following assertion was thrown attaching to the render tree:
> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
> 4357 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
>
> Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we
> should provide substantially more information in this error message to
> help you determine and fix the underlying cause. In either case,
> please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #2      Element.rebuild. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4357:14)
> #3      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4360:6)
> #4      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4643:5)
> #5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4638:5)
> #6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3673:14)
> #7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3425:18)
> #8      RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1198:16)
> #9      RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1167:5)
> #10     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree. (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1112:18)
> #11     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2573:19)
> #12     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1111:13)
> #13     WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:944:7)
> #14     WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget. (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:924:7) (elided 13 frames
> from class _AssertionError, class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer,
> dart:async, and dart:async-patch)

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please post your complete error log in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added bellow code to **ThemeCubit.dart** :

```
 bool isDarkMode = false;
 ThemeMode currentTheme(){
 isDarkMode?_setTheme(ThemeMode.dark) : _setTheme(ThemeMode.light);

      return isDarkMode?ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
 }

 void updateTheme(bool isDarkMode) {
 this.isDarkMode = isDarkMode;

}
```

and change **main.dart** :

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return  MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
           BlocProvider(
             create: (context) => ThemeCubit(),
          ),
       ],
       child:ElderlyApp(),     
    );
  }
  class ElderlyApp extends StatefulWidget {
     const ElderlyApp({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);
     @override
     _ElderlyAppState createState() => _ElderlyAppState();
  }

  class _ElderlyAppState extends State<ElderlyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

     @override
       void initState() {
           WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
           super.initState();
       }

      @override
     void didChangePlatformBrightness() {
        context.read<ThemeCubit>().currentTheme();
       super.didChangePlatformBrightness();
     }

     @override
     void dispose() {
        WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
        super.dispose();
    }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Production Boilerplate',
        theme: AppThemes.lightTheme,
        darkTheme: AppThemes.darkTheme,
        themeMode: context.select(
          (ThemeCubit cubit) => cubit.currentTheme()), //ThemeMode.dark,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
   }
  }
```

and change code in **seetingScreen.dart**

```
Positioned(
   top: 60 - widget.offset / 2,
   left: 20,
   child: Builder(builder: (context) {
   bool isDark = context.select((ThemeCubit themeCubit) =>
               themeCubit.state.themeMode) ==ThemeMode.dark ? true: false;
   return Switch(
                value: context.read<ThemeCubit>().isDarkMode,
                onChanged: (value) {
                context.read<ThemeCubit>().updateTheme(value);
              });
    })),
```